# After installing xpack on Kibana 5.0, the app fails to load

Tags: kibana, kibana-5, xpack

Kibana works fine with elasticsearch until I install xpack. I am using kibana and elasticsearch 5.0 on both and I am installing the 5.0 package of xpack.

The screen that I get after installing xpack is this
[image]

I tried restarting kibana but then the app would not show up at all. 
Does anyone know how to resolve this issue the logs are not showing any issues.

Comment: You installed `xpack` both ES and Kibana?

Comment: I did install it on both of the systems.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the solution here - https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/9414

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem and resolved by installing x-pack for both logstash and elasticsearch as well. I used below commands in windows 10 might be different depending on O/S

```
bin/elasticsearch-plugin install x-pack

bin/logstash-plugin install x-pack
```

Described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/installing-xpack.html)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the problem with installation. If you are running on any linux machines, do make sure you install x-pack with the same user that you installed kibana/elasticsearch. It is an issue often.

If not, do follow the process in the link to uninstall and reinstall again. It is very striaght forward and should work fine.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/installing-xpack.html

Also, do check if we need to make any changes in the configuration files- kibana.yml/elasticsearch.yml. This maynot be the case for here but it could help in debugging.